# Decompress Base64 Encoded Image Bytes in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, base64, compression

I am developing an iOS Application in Swift for use by customers of the company for which I work. In addition to the iOS application, I am also making the backend API with ASP.Net Core. The method I have chosen to use for sending images is a compressed base64 encoded string representation of the image in a JSON array. This is to save on bandwidth and to make it easier to send multiple images.

On the API side, I am using the .NET Class `System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream` to compress the image bytes in memory before encoding them to a base64 string and sending them to the iOS application.

On the iOS side, I am a little confused as to what the process would be for decoding the string and decompressing the data to create a `UIImage` object for display in a `UIImageView`.

This all works without compression, but I wanted to try this to save on bandwidth. However, it's very possible that this is not the optimal solution, and I am open to change. Below is the snippet of code I am using to convert the base64 string to a `Data` object, then creating a `UIImage` object from that.

```
static func imageComplete(data json: JSON) -> [UIImage] {
    var images: [UIImage] = []

    for imageString in json.arrayValue {
        if let compressedImageData = Data(base64Encoded: imageString.stringValue),
            let image = UIImage(data: compressedImageData) {

            images.append(image)
        }
    }
    return images
}
```

TL;DR
In Swift, I want to decompress image bytes encoded as a Base64 string returned from an ASP.Net Core WebAPI.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `DeflateStream` but after I read the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.deflatestream?view=netframework-4.7.2), I think it is one of compress/decompress algorithm. As you know, it has to be the same algorithm to compress/decompress. If you can't find any in swift, I don't think  you can use `DeflateStream` unless you make one. The `System.IO.Compression` also has other general comp algorithms like gzip. You can use them but I'm not sure compression really helps saving data.

Comment: The image file is already compressed and compressing it can make the size bigger. [Link](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8382/gzipped-images-is-it-worth)

Comment: I agree with @Ryan: Don't further compress it (assuming your image is in PNG, JPEG or similar format). Just base64 encode the PNG/JPEG binary data and add it as a string to your JSON object or array. If you decode this string on iOS, you get a `Data` instance and then can pass it to `UIImage`.

Comment: @Ryan Thank you for the information. Unfortunately, I was not aware of the bit about the algorithms needing to match. I am within my first year of programming, so I am still learning. The size of the uncompressed base64 strings are around 100KB for three images, so that should be sufficiently small. Hopefully. Thanks to you both for the help!

Comment: @Codo Thank you!